# How can I render a bar chart horizontally?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm rendering a bar chart with Kusto using `render barchart`. My expectation is to see columns displayed on x-axis. Unfortunately with render set to `barchart` the axis are swapped.  Is there an option to swap the axis in Kusto?

```
customEvents 
| summarize event_count=count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render barchart
```

Answer (score 6):

Silly me. There is dedicated render that swaps axis, and is called `columnchart`. More info about render can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer).

```
customEvents 
| summarize event_count=count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render columnchart
```